# How to return an integer in a python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example I am considering a very easy case. I want to write a function to check whether the given input number is even and return 2 if it is even and 1 if it is odd. I tried this:

```
a=int(input("Enter no. : "))
def isEven():

    if (a%2==0):
        return 2
    else:
        return 1

isEven()
```

But this is not returning anything. How to return 1 or 2 based on input? Thanks in advance for your time and help:)

Comment: It does return the number, but you never output it, so it's just thrown away

Comment: Yes. The computer won't do something you didn't request

Comment: The interactive interpreter will print the value of any expression after it is evaluated. The same is not true if you run the code non-interactively, such as with `python script.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function does return the number. You cannot see it because you didn't print it.

Besides, it's better to pass the number you want to check to the function as a parameter. The code should look somehow like this:

```
a = int(input("Enter no. : "))
def isEven(n):

    if (n % 2 == 0):
        return 2
    else:
        return 1

print(isEven(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

It works just that if you want to visualize it use `print()`:

```py
print(isEven())
```

Answer (score 0):

It is returning the value, just that you're not printing it

```
a=int(input("Enter no. : "))
def isEven():
    if (a%2==0):
        print("2")
    else:
        print("1")

isEven()
```

Or maybe something like this

```
a=int(input("Enter no. : "))
def isEven():
    if (a%2==0):
        return 2
    else:
        return 1

print(isEven())
```

Answer (score 0):

A function returns something in every case, if not returned anything specific, by default it return None.

Since in your case you have returned specific value. It's been returned to the function call. You can store the returned value in a variable.
Eg.

```
return_value = isEven()
```

Now you can either print return_value or use it in any other condition like:

```
print(return_value)
```

Or

```
if isEven(n):
    # your code
```

Hope it clears the doubt.